# Focus of EditText in ListView

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I currently having an issue with a bunch of EditText in a ListView

Every ListView item is defined like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemMainLabel"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the EditText of this field needs to gain focus no matter where I touch the list item.
To do this I tought the following `ItemClicked` event handler would work:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     TextView valueField = e.View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.valueEditText);
     if (valueField != null)
     {
          valueField.RequestFocus();
     }
}
```

But while the EditText is able gain focus whenever I click it (since this is default behaviour), the ItemClick event handler doesn't fire where ever I click in the list item.

What could be the cause of the event handler not firing and is there a way to make this work so that the EditText will gain focus whenever part of the item is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the `EditText` object into a `TextView` instance. So, Change this line...

```
TextView valueField = e.View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.valueEditText);
```

to...

```
EditText valueField = e.View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.valueEditText);
```

Comment: While that was a silly error on my part, changing the instance to a EditText didn't solve the focus issue (Since the eventhandler that contained the instance declaration doesn't even fire in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

By default both `TextView` and `EditText` will swallow your taps.  Try adding this to your `TextView`'s AXML:

`android:focusable="false"`

Comment: This did make the `ListView_ItemClick` method fire, however now the `RequestFocus` called in this method doesn't make the `EditText` focus anymore.